# iOS Error: cannot init a class object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am running some CloudCode (via Parse.com) in my iOS app. I am running that code in objective-C with this snippet right here:

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"email"
                   withParameters:@{@"email" : @"chumbleya@gmail.com", @"code" : @"TESTCODE"}
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@", result);
                                }
                                else {
                                    NSLog(@"%@", result);
                                }
                            }];
```

However, I get this error when I run it:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSMutableArray<0x3b6b4c00> init]: cannot init a class object.'
```

If anyone has had similar experience, let me know! Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at all the related question about the same error message? Certainly one or more can help you.

Comment: None of them seem to have the same underlying issue (I may be wrong). But, I've followed a ton of guides on how to set this all up, so I'm thinking it may be related to Parse

Comment: Have you commented out this specific code block to confirm that this is actually what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, the part where it is

```
...
withParameters:@{@"email" : @"chumbleya@gmail.com", @"code" : @"TESTCODE"}
...
```

would probably be

```
NSArray* keys = @[@"email", @"code"];
NSArray* values = @[@"chumbleya@gmail.com", @"TESTCODE"];
NSDictionary* aDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

...
withParameters:@[aDictionary]
...
```